# Duplicate symbols when integrating Firebase and Google Sign In SDKs manually without Cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am getting duplicate symbols error when integrating Firebase and Google Sign In SDKs manually in my existing iOS project.

The related SO question here didn't help as it uses Cocoapods.

[Firebase and Google Signin giving duplicate symbols error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812392/firebase-and-google-signin-giving-duplicate-symbols-error)

Steps I have taken in chronological order:

1. Copied Analytics, Auth and Database folder along with Firebase.h file from the downloaded Firebase SDK (3.11.0) into my project and added to targets.
2. Copied the GoogleService-Info.plist into the project and added to targets.
3. Added the -ObjC flag to other linker flags.
4. Copied the necessary frameworks and bundles from the downloaded Google Sign In SDK (4.0.1) into my project and added to targets.
5. Linked the necessary frameworks and libraries.

Here is the related project structure:

```
Firebase
    Analytics
        FirebaseAnalytics.framework
        FirebaseCore.framework
        FirebaseInstanceId.framework
        GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework
        GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
        GoogleToolboxForMac.framework
    Auth
        FirebaseAuth.framework
        GTMSessionFetcher.framework
GoogleSignIn
    GoogleAppUtilities.framework
    GoogleSignIn.bundle
    GoogleSignIn.framework
    GoogleSignInDependencies.framework
    GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework (removed as Firebase Analytics already includes it)
```

Here is the error log (truncated):

```
Ld /Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AddressBookGoogleMaps.app/AddressBookGoogleMaps normal x86_64
    cd /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics -F/Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth -F/Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Database -F/Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn -filelist /Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Intermediates/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddressBookGoogleMaps.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Intermediates/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddressBookGoogleMaps_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Intermediates/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/AddressBookGoogleMaps.app.xcent -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework GoogleSignInDependencies -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GoogleAppUtilities -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework FirebaseCore -framework GoogleSignIn -framework SafariServices -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework Accelerate -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseInstanceID -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Intermediates/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AddressBookGoogleMaps.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AddressBookGoogleMaps_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Ehtesham/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AddressBookGoogleMaps-hbtfxxvykazaogbfqnnraeuywtdt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AddressBookGoogleMaps.app/AddressBookGoogleMaps

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogStandardFormatter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogBasicFormatter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogNoFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogMaximumLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogMaximumLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMLogLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMLogAllowedLevelFilter in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Analytics/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMLogger_e66760ac68814bab22c3e6b0850da5e6.o)

........................................
........................................

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionFetcherService._cookieStorageMethod in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionFetcherService_c6b7326897506dd1305d6961fdc1ec8b.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionFetcherService_c6b7326897506dd1305d6961fdc1ec8b.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionFetcherService._retryEnabled in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionFetcherService_c6b7326897506dd1305d6961fdc1ec8b.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionFetcherService_c6b7326897506dd1305d6961fdc1ec8b.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadGranularity in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._shouldInitiateOffsetQuery in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._lastChunkRequest in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._initialBodySent in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._fetcherInFlight in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._currentOffset in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._useBackgroundSessionOnChunkFetchers in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._recentChunkReponseHeaders in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._delegateCompletionHandler in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._chunkFetcher in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadDataProvider in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMSessionFetcherUploadLocationObtainedNotification in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._initialBodyLength in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadFileLength in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._subdataGenerating in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._isSubdataGenerating in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMSessionUploadFetcherMaximumDemandBufferSize in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._chunkSize in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _kGTMSessionUploadFetcherStandardChunkSize in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._delegateCallbackQueue in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadMIMEType in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadFileHandle in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._recentChunkStatusCode in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._isPaused in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._isRestartedUpload in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadData in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadLocationURL in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionUploadFetcher._uploadFileURL in:
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignInDependencies.framework/GoogleSignInDependencies(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
    /Projects/iOS/AddressBookGoogleMaps/AddressBookGoogleMaps/Sources/Externals/Firebase/Auth/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher(GTMSessionUploadFetcher_fb894b20da0d1114d3ddd8f56ed741c5.o)
ld: 194 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is how I solved it although it is far from the ideal solution.

(This solution can be applied to any case where two static libraries cause "duplicate symbol" error due to both libraries containing common classes and using `-ObjC` or `-all_load` flag.)

Copy the GoogleSignInDependencies file inside the GoogleSignInDependencies.framework in a separate location PATH. This file is a fat file meaning it has codes for different architectures.

Open the terminal and go to PATH.

```
$ cd PATH
```

Run the command following command to get info about the fat library.

```
$ lipo -info GoogleSignInDependencies
```

You will get the following result.

```
Architectures in the fat file: GoogleSignInDependencies are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64
```

As you can see there are 4 architectures in the fat file.

Get the thin files (file that contains code for only one architecture) from the fat file by running the following commands.

```
$ lipo -thin armv7 GoogleSignInDependencies -output armv7.a
$ lipo -thin i386 GoogleSignInDependencies -output i386.a
$ lipo -thin x86_64 GoogleSignInDependencies -output x86_64.a
$ lipo -thin arm64 GoogleSignInDependencies -output arm64.a
```

You will get 4 thin files named armv7.a, i386.a, x86_64.a and arm64.a.

Delete the GoogleSignInDependencies file, we don't need it anymore.

Create 4 new folders named armv7, i386, x86_64 and arm64. Then move the thin files armv7.a, i386.a, x86_64.a and arm64.a to the respective folders. You should have a folder structure like the following.

```
arm64
    arm64.a
armv7
    armv7.a
i386
    i386.a
x86_64
    x86_64.a
```

Go to each of the 4 folders from terminal and extract the object files (*.o) from the thin files using the following commands.

```
$ cd armv7
$ ar -x armv7.a
$ cd ../i386
$ ar -x i386.a
$ cd ../x86_64
$ ar -x x86_64.a
$ cd ../arm64
$ ar -x arm64.a
```

After running these commands each of the 4 folders should contain the following files. (This can change in future versions.)

```
__.SYMDEF
GTMGeometryUtils_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMLogger_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMNSString+URLArguments_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMOAuth2Authentication_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMOAuth2SignIn_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionFetcher_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionFetcherLogging_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionFetcherService_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionUploadFetcher_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSynchronizationAsserts_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
```

Delete the files that are conflicting with the Firebase library from each of the 4 folders. You need to delete these 6 files. (This can change in future versions.)

```
GTMLogger_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionFetcher_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionFetcherLogging_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionFetcherService_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
GTMSessionUploadFetcher_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o
```

Delete the thin files armv7.a, i386.a, x86_64.a and arm64.a.

Combine the remaining object files into thin files by running the following commands.

```
$ cd armv7
$ libtool -static *.o -o armv7-new.a
$ cd ../i386
$ libtool -static *.o -o i386-new.a
$ cd ../x86_64
$ libtool -static *.o -o x86_64-new.a
$ cd ../arm64
$ libtool -static *.o -o arm64-new.a
```

Copy the newly created thin files armv7-new.a, i386-new.a, x86_64-new.a and arm64-new.a to a new location PATH_NEW. You can delete everything else inside PATH.

Combine the new thin files into a new fat file by running the following commands.

```
$ cd PATH_NEW
$ lipo -create armv7-new.a i386-new.a x86_64-new.a arm64-new.a -output GoogleSignInDependencies-new
```

Use the newly generated GoogleSignInDependencies-new in place of GoogleSignInDependencies in your Xcode project.

I strongly recommend the following article for deeper understanding of the things.

http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries

Comment: That is solution I was looking for. It's a shame for Google their own frameworks cannot be used together! For versions GoogleSignIn 4.0.1 and Firebase 4.0.2 only 2 .o symbols need to be removed: GTMLogger_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o and
GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.o. Thanks!

Comment: absolutely stunning solution. The symbols @FenixVoltres suggested to remove are also working for GoogleSignIn 4.1.0 and Firebase 4.4.0 !

Comment: Genius! Had been stuck on this for hoursss! :D

Comment: for me, I removed the following four .o files from your suggestion and it worked !
GTMSessionFetcher (arm64), GTMSessionUploadFetcher (arm64), GTMSessionFetcherService (arm64), GTMSessionFetcherService (arm64)

Answer (score 11):

## Update 2019-01-17 - Hacking Google SignIn is now redundant!

As per **xmasalov**'s reply below, Firebase has been updated to include all the dependencies needed for Google SignIn in the `/Invites` directory. Just add:

- GoogleSignIn.framework
- GTMOAuth2.framework
- GoogleToolboxForMac.framework

from that directory to you project. you no longer need to download the GoogleSignIn frameworks from Google at all.

#### My original reply (please ignore):

If you have this problem, I've just written a bash shell script which does all the work for me. I've saved it as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/drekka/87c507fe5265020e7be491216dc79aa8). use it at your own risk.

Please read all the comments above as the script may need tweaking to match changes in newer versions of the frameworks.

Comment: You are the absolute man! This works perfect! For the latest 4_1_0 make sure to change line 7 to ```duplicateClasses=(GTMLogger GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments)```

Comment: Works like a charm! I just had to comment out the last lines in the script that moved the framework out of the way and moved the created one in place. I dont know why but with the org script I just could not find the created framework. Now I just manually copy it from the “hack” folder. Great script!

Comment: The official Google Sign in SDK has now removed dependency on GTM OAuth 2 library so no GTMOAuth2.framework needed if you download the Google Sign In framework. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release.

Answer (score 10):

**Updated answer**

As of **2018-12**, Google Sign-In for iOS team removed dependency on the GTM OAuth 2 library.

> [Google Sign-In iOS SDK Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release)
>
> 2018-11-29 -- v4.4.0 Removed dependency on the GTM OAuth 2 library.

---

**Original answer**

As of **2018-11**, one can find all that is needed for **GoogleSignIn** to work with **FirebaseAnalytics** and **FirebaseAuth** in `Firebase/Invites` folder:

- `GoogleSignIn.framework`
- `GTMOAuth2.framework`

No need to add `GoogleSignInDependencies.framework`, works like a charm.

Comment: Lifesaver! and you may need to add GoogleSignin.bundle to copy bundle resources

Comment: If I read this correctly, it's now possible to avoid having to hack the frameworks. <Fingers-crossed>

Comment: this is convenient now

Comment: Confirmed. Please see my reply above for details.

Answer (score 4):

Here is why it's happening (true as of 2018-04-20):

1. Firebase depends on the GTMSessionFetcher library
2. GoogleSign in depends on both the GTMSessionFetcher library and GTMOAuth2 libraries

When CocoaPods are used, everything resolves beautifully because CocoaPods is a smart dependency manager and it deduplicates common dependencies.

When prebuild binaries are downloaded, things are a bit trickier...

- The Firebase zip file ships every dependency as a separate .framework. This means that if a framework is already being picked up from somewhere else, one can just manually remove the duplicate
- The GoogleSignIn zip file took another approach and bundled *all* dependencies into GoogleSignInDependencies.framework, meaning it contains *both* the GTMSessionFetcher and GTMOAuth2 frameworks

If one attempts to link as-is, the GTMSessionFetcher framework bundled into GoogleSignInDependencies will conflict with the standalone GTMSessionFetcher.framework shipped with Firebase

If the GoogleSignInDependencies framework is removed, the linker won't find the GTMOAuth2 framework and fail

Ideally, the GoogleSignIn zip file should contain the individual dependencies, making it more obvious as to what's going on. As it stands, there are two solutions to this problem:

**Easy:** Remove whatever is bundled in GoogleSignInDependencies from the frameworks that came with Firebase

- Under Frameworks/Firebase/Storage, remove GTMSessionFetcher.framework
- Under Frameworks/Firebase/Analytics, remove GoogleToolboxForMac.framework

**Harder:** Get rid of GoogleSignInDependencies

- Remove GoogleSignInDependencies.framework from the project
- Get a hold of GTMOAuth2.framework - I do not believe it's being distributed in binary form, so the easiest is to use CocoaPods to build a project containing it and grabbing the resulting framework from DerivedData

Comment: You have to go the hardest way, GoogleSignInDependencies are too old for Firebase 5. But you can find GTMOAuth2 in the Invites folder of Firebase SDK

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `GoogleSignInDependencies.framework` from `Link Binaries`

Answer (score -15):

The real question is; why are you directly copying instead of using cocoapods? There is really no advantage to using your method. If you use cocoapods you wont have this problem. If I were you I would remove these files and install with cocoapods. There is much less room for error when you install cocoapods

Comment: I'm having the same issue using cocoapods

Comment: when I use cocoapods I got an error saying Native Modules must not be null