# Duplicate symbols error when using Google Toolbox for Mac and Firebase Messaging

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, google-toolbox-for-mac

I have an iOS app which makes use of [Google Toolbox for Mac](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac) and Firebase Messaging. After running `pod update` to update to the newest version of FM, I get the following error after running Build on the Xcode project:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionFetcher._taskPriority in:
    .../Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/....build/Debug-iphonesimulator/....build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GTMSessionFetcher.o
    .../Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcher.a(GTMSessionFetcher.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionFetcher._servicePriority in:
    .../Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/....build/Debug-iphonesimulator/....build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GTMSessionFetcher.o

... // many more similar errors

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMSessionFetcherService._retryEnabled in:
    .../Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/....build/Debug-iphonesimulator/....build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GTMSessionFetcherService.o
    .../Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher/libGTMSessionFetcher.a(GTMSessionFetcherService.o)
ld: 147 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried the following:

- Disabling Bitcode
- Setting *No Common Blocks* to Yes (although this was already the case)

Can anyone advise? Unfortunately it looks like the FM version update is required, due to a bug in my current version, so the only way around it is to somehow fix these errors.

Comment: A probable solution for `GTMSessionFetcher` duplicate symbols is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/41569955/3339346

Comment: What does your podfile look like?  It looks like Cocoapods is failing to merge your app's GoogleToolboxForMac dependency and FM's GoogleToolboxForMac dependency into a single dependency.