# Firebase & Google Signin module conflicting in appcelerator

Tags: ios, xcode, appcelerator

I have been using firebasemodule & googlesignin module in iOS, when I build both modules together then we get below error:

> [ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> [ERROR] : The following build commands failed:
>
> [ERROR] : Ld
>   /Users/admin/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/testt/build/iphone/build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testt.app/testt
>   normal x86_64
>
> [ERROR] : (1 failure)

Later combine both module code into a single module, Module building & created properly but when I used the same module in My application again I got the same error as above.

link for both module

- https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-google-signin
- https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-core

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this @sandeep

Comment: Check-out the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217839/duplicate-symbols-when-integrating-firebase-and-google-sign-in-sdks-manually-wit